# Mysql output to csv putting column names on the bottom

Tags: mysql, csv, duplication

I'm trying to export the results of the query listed below to csv and have the column names in the first row. However, when I run the code and open up the csv the header is listed as the last row.  I have no idea why.  What am I missing?

```
SELECT 'id','state','First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Phone','County'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, state, First_Name, Last_Name, Phone, County
FROM tx.students
GROUP BY First_Name, Last_Name, Phone,
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY id
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/_students_dupes_test3.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Your query contradicts `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, so it selects random `Country` and `Phone` - does it is safe?

Comment: enclose second query by round brackets () - SELECT headers UNION ALL (query with order by) INTO ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The records order is defined by your `ORDER BY` clause expression. All `id` field values are converted to string type due to the type of the base (first) subquery field type. Of course the digits are first and letters last.

Replace it with

```
ORDER BY id='id' DESC, id
```